# Redirecting to previous page after log In, is just redirecting again and again back to log In form

Tags: php

After coming from somewhere page, there needs to log In and when it's correct, it should be redirected to last page but instead, it only back again to Log In form. Session already started in link.php, here is my php code

```
<?php
    include_once '../link.php';

    if (isset($_GET['login'])) { 
        if (isset($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password']) && !empty($_GET['password'])) {
            $username = $_GET['username'];
            $password = $_GET['password'];

            // Check if the username and password exist in the database (replace with your actual query)
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                                
                // Display Spinner and Redirect
                echo '<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center myBackground" style="height: 100vh;z-index:999; position:absolute; width:100%;height:135vh; padding-bottom:40vh;">
                <h3>Logging In</h3>
                <div class="spinner-border p-4 mt-3 mb-5" role="status">
                <span class="sr-only p-3 mb-5"></span>
                </div>
                </div>';

                echo '<script>
                // Redirect to the main page after 3 seconds
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = "' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '";
                }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds (1 second) delay before redirection
                </script>';
            } else {
                $error = "Invalid username or password";
            }
        } else {
            if(isset($_GET['username']) && !empty($_GET['username'])){
                $username=$_GET['username'];
            }
            else {
                $username_error="Please Fill Your Username";
            }
            
            if(isset($_GET['password']) && !empty($_GET['password'])){
                $password=$_GET['password'];
            }
            else {
                $password_error="Please Fill Your Password";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

No matter how many methods I tried like

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

or

`window.history.go(-1);`

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: When a user tries to access `/secure-page`, store `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in a session variable, _then_ redirect to the login page. Do your login stuff, and if your session variable is still set, redirect to that page, otherwise just pick a generic redirect to handle an edge case. Don't use JS for any of this at this point, you are asking for more trouble than it is worth. Always use a server-side redirect.

Comment: If you are rolling your own, whenever you build URLs that "do things", you should be aware of things like XSS, and learn about mitigations such as nonces and such.

Answer (score 0):

first of all your code has security issues. never use $_GET for getting information like username and passport always use POST method. Also your code is prone to MySQL injection because you are inserting $username and $passport inside your query without using prepared statenents. here is an example of prepared statement.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username); // 's' specifies the variable type => 'string'
$username = $_POST['user_input'];
$stmt->execute();
```

lets get back to your original question. Why your page goes to a loop of redirects. It seems like that you have another page named login.php that is your login form. that is your last page before current one and that's why your page is redirecting to it and this is totally natural.
to avoid this problem you it's better for you to redirect user to a welcome page after success.

```
<?php
if($success){
    header('location:/welcome.php');
}else{
    header('location:/login.php?problem=username_or_something');

}
?>
```